# Directory not accessible even though the read permission is given

Tags: linux

For a directory i have given following permission (read)

```
-rwxrw-r--. 1 sam sam 117 Feb  6 19:43 test_folder
```

when i try to access the test_folder with other user who does not belong to group sam . its giving error

```
-bash: cd: test_folder: Permission denied
```

even though the read permission is given to other users, still issue permssion issue

Comment: If you want to travel through you need `x`. `r` is just to let you list the names of the files inside. Read about access permissions.

Comment: There few file inside that folder . The permission to test_folder is given recursively (764). Then i should have access to the files inside test_folder. But its showing  Permission denied

Answer (score 2):

As suggested above: In order for other users to change to a directory, they need **execute** permissions on it. You should change the permissions of the directory as follows:

```
chmod 775 test_folder
```

The permissions will then change to something like:

```
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 sam sam 117 Feb  6 19:43 test_folder
```

Other users should then no longer get permission denied when using the `cd` command to navigate to `test_folder`.

See [this webpage](http://www.theunixschool.com/2010/05/file-permissions-vs-directory.html) for a more elaborate explanation of file/directory permissions. With regard to directories, it says:

> It is the executable permission on a directory which enables the user to get into the directory.

Compare this with:

> It is the read permission of the directory which enables the unix user to list the files inside the directory.

In general, read and execute permissions on directories are often given together.

Comment: Glad to hear it; if the answer completely resolves your original question, consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).